# Paypal Form Integration

Tags: php, forms, paypal

I am trying to integrate Paypal payment with a form registration. For example, a user would enter their information into form fields, press "register" and then they would be taken to Paypal where they pay a fee, upon payment the information they've submitted is posted in a file. I already have the information posting successfully into a file using a php, but now I want the process to wait for payment validation before posting. Is that possible?

Comment: Yes, you are looking for Paypal's IPN (Instant Payment Notification) - https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/products/instant-payment-notification/

Comment: I was trying that, but I wasn't having luck implementing it. Here is my "ipn.php" code maybe someone can spot what I am doing incorrectly. https://docs.google.com/document/d/1jwcPf7nI-ODvNZrF-nKwR6neLqGwFdZl3onCtMd3k0I/edit?usp=sharing